# Is it possible to get the last few lines of a logcat on a button click?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am trying to get the Logcat (at least last few lines) on a button click but nothing comes up -

```
view.findViewById(R.id.logdone).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Make file name.
        String fullName = "userlogs";

        // Extract to file.
        File file = new File(fullName);
        InputStreamReader reader = null;
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
          // get input stream
          String cmd = "logcat -d -v time";
          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
          reader = new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream());

          // write output stream
          writer = new FileWriter (file);
          char[] buffer = new char[10000];
          do 
          {
            int n = reader.read (buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (n == -1)
                break;
            writer.write (buffer, 0, n);
          } while (true);

          reader.close();
          writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          if (writer != null)
              try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
          if (reader != null)
              try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            }
          e.printStackTrace();
          return;
        }
      }
   }
```

**NOTE:**

I do have permissions -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

**UPDATE:**

My most of the content is in `Log.d()` then `Log.v()` then `Log.e()` then `Log.i()`. But how to get the last event lines on a button click. My purpose is to get those lines and send them via email to the developer.

I am using the popular third party API known as `ACRA` to send email which is working fine.
I can use `StringBuilder` to put all my device logs into it and then to send via email.
But I am unable to get.

Any elegant way that works well effectively ?

Comment: You can try put content inside Log.v() ?

Comment: My most of the content is in `Log.d()` then `Log.v()` then `Log.e()` then `Log.i()`. But how to get the last event lines on a button click. My purpose is to get those lines and send them via email to the developer.

Comment: According to a comment on this post, the `READ_LOGS` permission is no longer granted to non-system apps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326949/android-app-using-android-permission-read-logs-is-that-impolite.

Comment: You could just extend Log class and save last lines your self, should be quick and easy.

Comment: @somerandomusername Can you show example usage. I couldn't make out extending Log class.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time right now to do this. So just create new class that passes data to Log class. And just before doing it save it to memory.

Answer (score 2):

Given the comment I made about the `READ_LOGS` permission no longer being granted to non-system apps, I would instead recommend using a [`MemoryHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html) with a standard Java [`Logger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Logger.html).  On a button click, you can [`push`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html#push%28%29) the messages to a target [`StreamHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html) (which you can use to just dump them into the output buffer of your choice).

Comment: So do I need to write logs of standard Java Logger in my every class like `logger.info("my class")` and can't use my pre-existing logs like `Log.d()` or `Log.e()` ?

Comment: @VedPrakash Well, short of that, you can make your own `Log` class in your package which handles the `d()`, `e()`, etc. methods, forwarding them on to the logger.  Then you don't have to change your individual usages of `Log.d()`, `Log.e()`, etc.

Comment: @VedPrakash ... Of course, your implementations of `d()`, `e()`, etc. could also call the `android.util.Log` class implementations before forwarding the messages to the `Logger`, such that the messages go to *both* Logcat and the Java logger/handler.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get the last few lines of a logcat on a button click?

There has never been a documented and supported way for apps to get anything from LogCat. And, as Turix notes, [things were locked down further in Android 4.2](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html).

> Any elegant way that works well effectively ?

Log the data yourself to a file that you control, rather than (or in addition to) logging the data to LogCat.

Comment: But as you commented out in those posts - "ACRA does not need READ_LOGS. Certain ACRA features might need READ_LOGS.". So can ACRA do that to capture logs without a permission ?

Comment: I am also getting the following message when I run ACRA - "READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data." But still the Logcat is empty.

Comment: @VedPrakash: Correct. ACRA is using undocumented and unsupported means to read LogCat. And, at best, all it can get are lines logged by the app itself, not from other pieces of Android that you may be working with (e.g., the media subsystem). AFAIK, they are using the same sort of run-the-`logcat`-command thing that you are trying. ACRA is open source, so you can examine it and see for yourself. Just understand that using LogCat this way adds no value over you logging to your own file, and adds the risk that LogCat gets locked down further still in the future and screws up your code.